# Change only a part of text file using AWK in TCL

Tags: awk, tcl, ns2

I want to change only particular value of text file using AWK and retain rest of the values as it is.

The input file, *ene.txt:*

```
energy_of_node 1 48.03004556
energy_of_node 2 56.05655687
energy_of_node 3 48.03004556
energy_of_node 4 56.05655687
energy_of_node 5 48.03004556
energy_of_node 6 56.05655687
energy_of_node 7 48.03004556
energy_of_node 8 56.05655687
```

I need to change value of variable which is fed by TCL.

*my_code.tcl:*

```
to_node = 7
exec awk -f drain.awk -v var=$to_node ene.txt
```

*drain.awk:*

```
#Here I need to alter the value of var to 0.000100
BEGIN{} {
if($2 == var) { 
$3==0.000100 
# but this definitely will not work, since this changes the entire file.  
}
}
END {
}
```

Comment: Note that `to_node = 7` in Tcl calls a **command** named `to_node` with 2 arguments. To set a variable, use `set to_node 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call out to awk at all:

```
set in [open ene.txt r]
set tempfile /tmp/ene.txt.[pid].[clock seconds]
set out [open $tempfile w]
while {[gets $in line] != -1} {
    set fields [split $line]
    if {[lindex $fields 1] == 7} {
        lset fields 2 0.000100
    }
    puts $out [join $fields]
}
close $in
close $out
file rename -force $tempfile ene.txt
```

Comment: Yes. This works. But I want changes to be done to existing file itself since I am using this in a loop which keeps changing the values as per randomly generated input values. Help out if there is any way to do the changes to the input file itself.

Comment: Updated to overwrite the existing file

Comment: Great ! This works. Could you please explain about set tempfile /tmp/ene.txt.[pid].[clock seconds]. What would this do?

Comment: @shim_mang See [pid](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/pid.htm) and [clock seconds](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm#M11). These are being used to create a unique temporary file name.

Comment: A better way to create a temp filename is in [tcllib](http://tcllib.sf.net): `package require fileutil; set tempfile [::fileutil::tempfile]`

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
exec awk -v var=$to_node {$2==var{$3="0.00010"}1} ene.txt
```

Note that awk programs follow the following scheme:

```
CONDITION { ACTION } [ CONDITION2 { ACTION2 } ... ]
```

where `{ ACTION }` is optional. If you don't specify it, awk will print the current line.

The program above contains two of these expressions:

```
$2==var { $3 = "0.00010" }
1
```

The first one checks if the the condition `$2==var` is true and executes the action `{ $3 = "0.00010" }` in that case.

The second just contains a condition: `1`, which will always evaluate to true and will print the current line since no action has been specified.

---

Btw, the above command doesn't output anything because you missed to print it. You need `puts`:

```
puts [exec awk -v var=$to_node {$2==var{$3="0.00010"}1} ene.txt]
```

---

If you want the results back to the original file you need to use something like this:

```
set to_node 7
# Execute awk and store the output in $result
set result [exec awk -v var=$to_node {$2==var{$3="0.00010"}1} a.txt ]
# Open the file for writing and truncate it to zero length
set fd [open "a.txt" "w"]
# Write the result back to the file
puts $fd $result
# Close the file
close $fd
```

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for your edit! I missed that strings aren't enclosed in  quotes in TCL.

Comment: This is not working for me. I am clueless. It does not throw any errors too !

Comment: This is because you don't output the results. If you want to change the file in place you need to obtain the results and then save it back to `ene.txt`. `awk` doesn't change the file in place.

Comment: Added `puts`. Now you should be able to see the results. However, I would have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30154724/171318) answer. You don't need `awk` at all.

Comment: Using this I can redirect the updated text file to another file. But is that possible to change in the existing file itself?

Comment: Have added that to my answer.

Comment: I'm glad to see that it helped you, however I would still have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30154724/171318) solution and add the file saving behaviour as shown above. Good luck! :)